# How can I print a Numpy Array as a result from a function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, printing

I have this function which gets 3 inputs and does some matrix calculations.

```
import numpy as np

def func(input_x, output_y, lambda_param):
        
    if input_x.shape[0]<input_x.shape[1]:
        input_x = np.transpose(input_x)
    
    input_x = np.c_[np.ones(input_x.shape[0]),input_x]
    
    lambda_param = np.identity(input_x.shape[1])*lambda_param
    

    a = np.linalg.inv(lambda_param+np.matmul(np.transpose(input_x),input_x))
    b = np.matmul(np.transpose(input_x),output_y)

    weights = np.matmul(a,b)
    weights = np.array([weights])
    return weights
```

The function works well but I have a problem with the data type of the result. For example I have the inputs yy, xx and lamb:

```
yy = np.array([208500, 181500, 223500, 
                                140000, 250000, 143000, 
                                307000, 200000, 129900, 
                                118000])
                                
xx = np.array([[1710, 1262, 1786, 
                                1717, 2198, 1362, 
                                1694, 2090, 1774, 
                                1077], 
                               [2003, 1976, 2001, 
                                1915, 2000, 1993, 
                                2004, 1973, 1931, 
                                1939]])
lamb = 10

result = func(xx, yy, lamb)

print(result) #--> np.array([-576.67947107,   77.45913349,   31.50189177])
#print(result[2]) #--> 31.50189177
```

`print(result)` gives me `[[-576.67947107   77.45913349   31.50189177]]`
but should return a numpy.array like `np.array([-576.67947107,   77.45913349,   31.50189177])`

and `print(result[2])` should return `31.50189177` but gives an error because its not a np.array?

I hope you can help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `weights = np.array(weights)` instead of `weights = np.array([weights])`?

Comment: I tried this but this would return ```[-576.67947107   77.45913349   31.50189177]
31.501891773638363 ```but not ```np.array([...])```

Comment: try checking the datatype of result using _type(result)_. For me it is showing numpy.ndarray.

Comment: `print(arr)` shows the `str` format of the array, which omits the work `array` and commas.  The `repr` gives more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this line: `weights = np.array([weights])`
weights is already a 1D numpy array after `weights = np.matmul(a,b)`. The redundant line will give an extra dimension to weights and the shape of weights becomes (1,3). You can check these by using print(weights.shape)

Answer (score 1):

Removing the second to last line of func (`weights = np.array([weights])`) should fix it for you. You're unintentionally creating a two-dimensional array with that line. For example:

```py
x = np.array([0.25, 0.50, 0.75])
print(x.shape)  #--> (3,) 
print(x[2])  #--> 0.75

y = np.array([x])
print(y.shape) #--> (1, 3)
print(y[2])  #--> IndexError
```

`y` above is a 2D array with length 1 in the first index and length 3 in the second index, so `y[2]` (which applies to the first index) doesn't exist.

You could do `np.array(weights)` instead (without putting weights in a list), but that's obsolete as `weights` is already a numpy array.

In terms of what's printed - you can check that `weights` really is a numpy array by doing `print(type(weights))`. It is a numpy array even if this isn't clear from `print(weights)`.

Comment: thank you, very simple but i didnt see it, now it works